# Don't understand jquery connection?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am attempting to run some jquery code on my website, yet the code wasn't working as expected. I have tried several different sets of code thinking that my code was the problem. Though as I tested a simple class change in jquery the code still didn't work. So I am wondering if it's my connection to the jquery files. Take a look at my set up.

In the head tags i have the following.

```
<script src="Script/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="Script/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="Script/HomePageDDL.js"></script>
```

This is in by body tags

```
<div id="MainContent">
    <h1 id="toggle" class="h1Example">Jquery Test</h1>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
$('#toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('newH1Example');
});
```

Here is my CSS

```
.h1Example {
color: green;
}

.newH1Example {
color: green;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}
```

Comment: remove `<script src="Script/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>`. Don't include jquery twice

Comment: you don't want to include jquery twice, the reason they give you both options is because one is minified, this means variable names are simplified and spaces are removed. Minified versions load faster, but are harder to debug

Comment: Remove one of the jQuery you're including. Let the `min` version.

Comment: I think it may be important to understand the difference between `min` and, well, `not min` js files.

Comment: jquery-1.11.3.min.js is just a "minified" version of jquery, there is no reason to have both. Usually you want to use the minified version for production and the expanded version for debugging.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6nxmbc90/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including jquery twice in your html. Remove either of them. In case you need to run in production, use the minified version as it small compact (removed spaces, etc). If you want to run in development mode, when you need to debug, use the non-minified version.

```
<script src="Script/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="Script/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

You need to update your JS too.

Add jquery ready for your JS. This is required as you need to make sure all the binding is done once the document is ready. If you do not use the document ready, then that element will not necessarily be available in the DOM, hence, event will not be binded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('newH1Example');
    });

});
```

I hope it helps!!!

Comment: @Regis - Yes please tell me the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment because I figured it out.
I thought that according to W3 schools the $(document).ready
was no longer necessary (http://goo.gl/RQui). I miss read the document however. You still need it, there is just a shortened form that you can use.

Thank you for your help.